# redirect port to another machine

Tags: linux, port-forwarding

**My poblem:**

At work I have a proxy with some closed ports. I need to connect to an Oracle DB on some DB_IP at port 1521. DB_IP is a public IP.

**What I Have:**

At home, I have a Linux machine and a Linksys WRT54G Router.

**What I need:**

How can I do to communicate a PC at work with DB_IP:1521?

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your SSH server and port forwarding to accomplish this.  Just connect to your SSH server on your linux machine using a [remote forwarded port](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1):

```
ssh -R 15210:DB_IP:1521 user@example.com
```

Then point your app that needs to talk to the DB to `localhost:51210`.  That port can actually be any port you like, just make sure you make the appropriate change to the SSH command above if you change it.  This command allocates a socket on your machine which is forwarded to `DB_IP:1521` through your linux machine.